# Rearranging the columns in all the sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have six sheets in a workbook, And in 2 sheets i have 40 columns and other four sheets i have 44 columns, so when i consolidate all the sheets value are not coming properly, so first i planned to rearrange the columns in all the sheet, As in my raw data the heading is starting from row 11, so in the code itself i am deleting first 10 rows, then my header will start from the first row, In my below code rows are getting deleted in all the sheet but columns are getting rearranged in the first sheet only other sheets columns are in the same place. Any one can help me out to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

For the reference, Please find my code below.

```
Sub gram_em()
Dim ws As Worksheet, xWs As Worksheet
 strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
  Application.Workbooks.Open (strFile)

For Each ws In Sheets
 If ws.Visible Then ws.Select (False)
Next

Set xWs = ActiveSheet
Rows("1:10").Select    
Selection.Delete    
Range("A1").Select    
xWs.Select

Set xWs = ActiveSheet    
Range("A1").Select
arrColOrder = Array("BA ID", "BA Name", "Project Number", "Project 
Name", "Service Month", "Last Action Perfromed by")
counter = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)
    Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column <> counter Then
            Found.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(counter).Insert shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next ndx
xWs.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
End Sub
```

Comment: In your second loop you are not referencing any worksheets, unlike your first.

Comment: i am not referencing any worksheets, Just uploading the workbook after that  in all the worksheets it has to rearrange the columns.

Comment: You are using Find to find the headings, but unless they are in exactly the same place in very sheet you need to loop through the individual sheets.

Comment: So how to loop in all the sheets,Can you tell me,  because i don't know how and where to put the loop in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your logic is sound, try this. It extends the loop. Note that you don't need to select anything.

```
Sub gram_em()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, Found as Range, ndx as Long, counter as Long

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
arrColOrder = Array("BA ID", "BA Name", "Project Number", "Project Name", "Service Month", "Last Action Perfromed by")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    If ws.Visible Then
        ws.Rows("1:10").Delete
        counter = 1
        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)
            Set found = ws.Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                If found.Column <> counter Then
                    found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    ws.Columns(counter).Insert shift:=xlToRight
                End If
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next ndx
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```